# How to fix Dictionary look up text color in Dark mode?

Tags: color, dictionary, dark-mode, look-up, css

In macOS Mojave dark mode, the Dictionary app became unusable because of coloring issues: in application itself some of the text is white on white, and in definition popup that appears if you right click a word and select Look Up (or use force touch or three-finger press) the text is black on a dark grey background:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it's working very well.

Comment: Hi @keramzyt they must be glad it worked for you. Please vote for good content as only the asker can tick the accepted control on an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching the Internet and experimenting I was able to produce a solution. You have to create a `DefaultStyle.css` file and put it in `Contents` subdirectory for each dictionary you want to fix. The dictionaries are located at `~/Library/Dictionaries` or at `/System/Library/Assets/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX/` folders. You can easily open them in Finder by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and pasting the folder path. Here's the `DefaultStyle.css` contents:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@namespace d url(http://www.apple.com/DTDs/DictionaryService-1.0.rng);


@media (prefers-dark-interface)
{

    html {
        -apple-color-filter: apple-invert-lightness();
    }

    a {
        -apple-color-filter: none;
        color: -webkit-link;
    }

    img {
        filter: invert(100%);
    }

    html.apple_client-panel body div {
        color: text;
    }

    html.apple_client-panel body div.L1 {
        color: -apple-system-label;
    }

}
```

It uses `@media (prefers-dark-interface)` selector to apply this CSS only in dark mode. The `html.apple_client-panel` is the selector for a popup window that appears when you use the Define/Look Up feature. After applying the fix the Dictionary looks good and is readable again:

[image: screenshot of the fixed problem]

Comment: Thank you for troubleshooting the issue and for the workaround! Could you mark your answer as accepted? To do this, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. This shows other people who have this issue that this question has a "good" answer.